# How avoid page size reduction on report load in pentaho reporting?

Tags: html, reporting, pentaho

In report i wrote custom toggle function which wrap items by default(in first load user see only few items on top level of groups).

In preview mode (i'm using pentaho report designer 6.1.0.1-196) all works fine.
If i deploy report and try to view from web: report now have constant height. When group expanded height remain constant and part of data now invisible (html-paginated or single-page has same result).

How can i increase page size?

Some thoughts: i think report server building page based on minimal required space for report, and may be some trick to say server that report have more lines.

[image: screenshot]